# Run asp.net core console application on Linux or Mac

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2015, console-application, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created one console application in asp.net core in window PC and create a .sln file(vs 2017).

Now, I will need to run the same .sln file on Linux / Mac visual studio 2017.
I have no idea how it will run.
Can you give me hint or solution regarding that ?

Comment: What do you mean by run a `.sln` file ?  A solution is a text-based file that can be read by Visual Studio / Visual Studio Code .  You cannot use Visual Studio on Linux .  Are you want to deploy on Linux/Mac ?  Or are you want to develop a asp.net core application on Linux ?

Comment: @itminus I have developed the asp.net core project in visual studio (windows os).Now, same project I will need to run or update the project on another system which are Mac or Linux.so,How can I do it ?

Comment: If you want to let your project running on Mac /Linux/ Raspberry Pi, just deploy it by `dotnet publish -c Release` ; If you want to develop netcore apps on Linux , simply use the VSCode . There's also a Visual Studio for Mac .

Comment: Ok got it ,so no need to extra installation except to vscode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let your project running on Mac /Linux/ Raspberry Pi, just deploy it by dotnet publish -c Release ;

If you want to develop netcore apps on Linux , simply use the VSCode . There's also a Visual Studio for Mac .

One more thing you can directly code from TFS this is better way.